# SFINAE with concepts

Tags: c++, c++20, sfinae, c++-concepts

I have an abstract base class and then a templated derived class, for certain types (specified by a template), I want to implement the virtual base methods in the derived class, for others, this should be left open (with the need for a further derivation):

```cpp
#include <iostream>

struct cat {
void meow() {
        std::cout << "Meow!\n";
    }
};

struct base {
    virtual void foo_base() = 0;
};

template<typename T>
concept can_meow = requires(T t){t.meow();};

template<class T>
struct derived: public base {
derived() requires can_meow<T> {
    std::cout << "Wrapper constructor with meow!\n";
}

derived() requires (!can_meow<T>) {
    std::cout << "Wrapper constructor w/o meow!\n";
}

void foo_base() requires can_meow<T> final {};
};

template<class T>
struct derived2: public derived<T> {
    void foo_base() final {};
};

int main() {
    derived<cat> c; //works
    //derived2<int> i; //error
    return 0;
}
```

How do I get this to work? The error I'm currently getting is:

```
<source>:28:6: error: use of function 'void wrapper<T>::foo_base() requires  can_meow<T> [with T = int]' with unsatisfied constraints
```

Cheers and thanks

Update: godbolt https://godbolt.org/z/T4v7Yjq5f

Comment: clang says: `<source>:33:18: error: virtual function cannot have a requires clause`  https://godbolt.org/z/cnovKccnK

Answer (score 4):

You are not allowed to constrain a virtual function in any way (See: [[class.virtual]p6](https://wg21.link/class.virtual#6)).

You can achieve a similar effect by having a conditional base class that could override the function. For example:

```cpp
namespace detail {
    template<class T>
    struct derived_impl : base {
        using base::base;
    };

    template<can_meow T>
    struct derived_impl<T> : base {
        using base::base;

        void foo_base() final {}
    };
}

template<class T>
struct derived: detail::derived_impl<T> {
    derived() requires can_meow<T> {
        std::cout << "Wrapper constructor with meow!\n";
    }

    derived() requires (!can_meow<T>) {
        std::cout << "Wrapper constructor w/o meow!\n";
    }
};
```

Comment: clang states this clearly: `<source>:33:18: error: virtual function cannot have a requires clause`  https://godbolt.org/z/cnovKccnK

Answer (score 3):

As @artyer already noted, you cannot constrain virtual functions this way.  The technique of introducing a conditional intermediate class is a good one, but you can do some CRTP trickery to make it less intrusive.

```
template<class D, class B, bool route_foo>
struct foo_router:B {
  using B::B;
};
template<class D, class B>
struct foo_router<D,B, true>:B {
  using B::B;
  void foo_base() final {
    return static_cast<D*>(this)->foo_base_impl();
  }
};
```

then we do:

```
template<class T>
struct derived: public foo_router<derived<T>, base, can_meow<T>> {
  derived() requires can_meow<T> {
    std::cout << "Wrapper constructor with meow!\n";
  }

  derived() requires (!can_meow<T>) {
    std::cout << "Wrapper constructor w/o meow!\n";
  }

  void foo_base_impl() requires can_meow<T> /*final*/ {};
};

template<class T>
struct derived2: public derived<T> {
  void foo_base() final {};
};
```

the `foo_router` conditionally routes `foo_base` to `foo_base_impl` depending on `can_meow<T>`.  In this implementation, it exists regardless, but does nothing if `!can_meow<T>`.

[Live example](https://godbolt.org/z/WajqE94qz) - the changes are isolated to renaming and stripping `final` from `foo_base_impl`, the extra `router` class, and inheritance from `derived`.

We can make this more light weight:

```
template<class D, class B, bool route_foo>
using foo_router_t = std::conditional_t<route_foo, foo_router<D,B,route_foo>, B>;
```

this eliminates the empty `foo_router` type at compile time.  Having fewer types can save on compile time and memory use.

```
template<class T>
struct derived: public foo_router_t<derived<T>, base, can_meow<T>>
```